Asymptotic behaviour of $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty f_1(x+z)f_2(x)dx$ in $z\to+\infty$?
Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be two positive continuous functions defined on $\mathbb{R}_+$ and $a_1,a2>0$ such that:
$$f_1(x)\sim_{+\infty} e^{-a_1 x}\quad\mathrm{ and } \quad f_2(x)\sim_{+\infty} e^{-a_2 x}.$$
Let define the function $\varphi$ as:
$$\forall z>0, \varphi(z):= \int_0^\infty f_1(x+z)f_2(x)dx.$$
How can we derive an asymptotiv behaviour for $\varphi$ in $+\infty$ ?
My intuition is that we will have $\varphi(x)\sim_{+\infty} Ze^{-a_1x}$ where $Z>0$, but I couldn't prove antything until here.
My attempt
What I want to prove is that $e^{a_1z}\varphi(z)$ has a positive limit for $z$ tending to $+\infty$. We have:
$$e^{a_1z}\varphi(z) = \int_{\mathbb{R}_+}e^{a_1z}f_1(x+z)f_2x)dx.$$
We know that for $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\eta>0$ such that:
$$\forall y\geq \eta, \quad |f_1(y)e^{a_1 y}-1|\leq \epsilon.$$
We have then:
\begin{align*}
e^{a_1z}\varphi(z) &= \int_0^\infty e^{a_1z}f_1(x+z)f_2(x)dx\\
&= \int_0^{\max(\eta-z,0)} e^{a_1z}f_1(x+z)f_2(x)dx + \int_{\max(\eta-z,0)}^\infty e^{a_1z}f_1(x+z)f_2(x)dx
\end{align*}
The first integral convreges to 0. Now, the second integral can be bound by:
$$(1-\epsilon)\int_{\max(\eta-z,0)}^\infty f_2(x)dx\leq \int_{\max(\eta-z,0)}^\infty e^{a_1z}f_1(x+z)f_2(x)dx \leq (1+\epsilon)\int_{\max(\eta-z,0)}^\infty f_2(x)dx$$
We lower bound again and it comes:
\begin{align*}
(1-\epsilon)\int_{\max(\eta-z,0)}^\infty f_2(x)dx &\geq (1-\epsilon)\int_\eta^\infty f_2(x)dx\\
(1+\epsilon)\int_{\max(\eta-z,0)}^\infty f_2(x)dx &\leq (1+\epsilon)\int_0^\infty f_2(x)dx
\end{align*}
I am stuck here because my bounds doesn't converge to some constants...
Thank you very much!

$e^{-a_1(x+z)}=e^{-a_1x}e^{-a_1z}$.

Thank you for your comments, for the equality case suggested by @AnneBauval, we have: $\varphi(z) = Ke^{-a_1 z}$ where $K$ is a constant defined by $\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}e^{-(a_1+a_2)x}dx$. Am I wrong ?

What you can show is $\varphi(z)\sim\operatorname e^{-a_1z}\int_0^\infty\operatorname e^{-a_1x}f_2(x),\mathrm dx$. But I don't think you can “discard” $f_2$ in general.

@AnneBauval: I updated the post, thank you!

@nejimban: could you show me how to proceed ? Thank you very much!

Thank you for your precise remarks! I think it doesn't change that the bounds converge to each others...

More generally, let $f_1,f_2,g\in L^1(\Bbb R_+)$ such that $f_2,g\ge0$ and $$f_1\underset\infty\sim g.$$ We shall prove that $$\int_0^\infty f_1(x+z)f_2(x)dx\underset{z\to\infty}\sim\int_0^\infty g(x+z)f_2(x)dx.$$ Applied to your special case, whith $g(x)=e^{-a_1x}$, this will give $$\varphi(z)\underset{z\to\infty}\sim\int_0^\infty e^{-a_1(x+z)}f_2(x)dx=e^{-a_1z}\int_0^\infty e^{-a_1x}f_2(x)dx.$$
Note that no asymptotic for $f_2$ is needed.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. There exists $\eta>0$ such that
$$\forall y\geq \eta, \quad |f_1(y)-g(y)|\le\epsilon g(y).$$
We have then, for every $z\ge\eta$:
$$\begin{align}\left|\int_0^\infty f_1(x+z)f_2(x)dx-\int_0^\infty g(x+z)f_2(x)dx\right|&=\left|\int_0^\infty\left(f_1(x+z)-g(x+z)\right)f_2(x)dx\right|\\
&\le\int_0^\infty\left|f_1(x+z)-g(x+z)\right|f_2(x)dx\\&\le\epsilon\int_0^\infty g(x+z)f_2(x)dx,
\end{align}$$
Q.E.D.

Thank you very much @Annebauval for this nice and more general derivation (and much simpler)!

I assume that $\int_0^\infty\operatorname e^{-a_1x}f_2(x)\,\mathrm dx$ exists. Let $\varepsilon>0$. There exists $A_0>0$ such that for all $x\ge A_0$,
\begin{align*}
  \left|f_1(x)-\operatorname e^{-a_1x}\right|\le\varepsilon\operatorname e^{-a_1x},\\[.4em]
  \left|f_2(x)-\operatorname e^{-a_2x}\right|\le\varepsilon\operatorname e^{-a_2x}.
\end{align*}
Then, for all $A\ge A_0$ and $z\ge A$,
\begin{align*}
\varphi(z)
&=\int_0^Af_1(x+z)f_2(x)\,\mathrm dx
+\int_A^\infty f_1(x+z)f_2(x)\,\mathrm dx\\[.4em]
&\le\int_0^A(1+\varepsilon)\operatorname e^{-a_1(x+z)}f_2^+(x)\,\mathrm dx
-\int_0^A(1-\varepsilon)\operatorname e^{-a_1(x+z)}f_2^-(x)\,\mathrm dx\\[.4em]
&\hspace{6em}+\int_A^\infty(1+\varepsilon)^2\operatorname e^{-(a_1+a_2)x}\operatorname e^{-a_1z}\mathrm dx\\[.4em]
&\le\operatorname e^{-a_1z}\bigl(1+O(\varepsilon)\bigr)\left[\int_0^A\operatorname e^{-a_1x}f_2(x)\,\mathrm dx+\frac{\operatorname e^{-(a_1+a_2)A}}{a_1+a_2}\right]\!.
\end{align*}
It follows that
$$\limsup_{z\to\infty}\:\operatorname e^{a_1z}\varphi(z)\le\bigl(1+O(\varepsilon)\bigr)\left[\int_0^A\operatorname e^{-a_1x}f_2(x)\,\mathrm dx+\frac{\operatorname e^{-(a_1+a_2)A}}{a_1+a_2}\right]\!.$$
Letting now $A\to\infty$, then $\varepsilon\to0^+$, this shows that
$$\limsup_{z\to\infty}\:\operatorname e^{a_1z}\varphi(z)\le\int_0^\infty\operatorname e^{-a_1x}f_2(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$
Proceeding similarly for the lower bound (or using the above inequality with $f_2$ replaced by $-f_2$) produces
$$\liminf_{z\to\infty}\:\operatorname e^{a_1z}\varphi(z)\ge\int_0^\infty\operatorname e^{-a_1x}f_2(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$
We conclude that
$$\varphi(z)\underset{z\to\infty}\sim\operatorname e^{-a_1z}\int_0^\infty\operatorname e^{-a_1x}f_2(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$

Thank you @nejimban for this super answer! Coul you precise me what you mean by $f_2^\pm$ please ?

Scuse me, finally deduced that it was positive/negative part. Thank you!

Last question @nejimban: do you think that it is true that if $f_1(x)\sim \psi_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)\sim\psi_2(x)$, there exists $Z>0$ such that $\varphi(z)=_{+\infty} = O(\psi_1(z))$ (provided some constraints on the integrability of the two functions ? )

@NancyBoy You would need some nice assumptions on $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$. Just writing “$f_i(x)\sim\psi_i(x)$ for some $\psi_i$” does not bring much information if we can take $f_i=\psi_i$. You could try to adapt my proof to a more general setting and see what additional assumption one would need.

(Under the OP's hypothesis) $\int_0^\infty\operatorname e^{-a_1x}f_2(x),\mathrm dx$ does exist.
